# Convert data URL (of type blob://xxx) to IRandomAccessStream

Tags: windows-runtime, blob, winjs

I have an internal API (that I have no control over) which returns a URL of an image. I inspected the URL and noticed that it's has the following format:

```
blob://xxxxxxxx
```

I use this URL as a value for `img.src` in my code, and that displays the image perfectly. Now, I'd like to convert this URL to a `IRandomAccessStream` object so I can call another internal API.

I tried the following:

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(imgUrl);
var streamRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.createFromUri(uri);
streamRef.openReadAsync(function (stream) {
    // stream is of type IRandomAccessStream
    // make internal API call here
}, error);
```

However, I get a "Not implemented" error message in my error handler function for the `openReadAsync` call.

Is there another way to convert a blob URL to an IRandomAccessStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will give access to a blob object from the URL of format (blob:B0939E98-128B-4BA3-B8D6-B499E7F6C612). This is as per [w3 File API spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url) section 12.7.

```
// url like example: blob:B0939E98-128B-4BA3-B8D6-B499E7F6C612
WinJS.xhr({ url: url, responseType: 'blob'}).then(function (req)
{
    var blob = req.response;
}).then(null, function onerror()
{
    // handle error
});
```

After that using [FileReader api](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader), you can read the contents of the blob. [mozilla doc link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFileReader) for FileReader api. If there is a specific reason to build IRandomAccessStream, need to explorer converting a blob object to IRandomAccessStream.

Comment: did you read using filereader or converted blob to randomaccessstream. your notes might help someone else.